# Create Active/Archive Models in a DRY way (Django)

Tags: mysql, django, class, inheritance, model

I have a model like the following, which is growing too large and needs to be split into a separate active table.  At the end of the day, one table will contain all objects and the other will only contain active objects.

```
   class Tickets(models.Model):
        price = ....
        number = .....
        date = ....
        active = ....
        parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='children')

        ManyMoreFields
```

There are two sources of complexity:

1) The parent field on the ActiveTickets table is going to point to the Tickets table.  The related_name should not change.

2) The ActiveTickets and Tickets table both have proxy Models that inherit from them.

```
     class CityTickets(Tickets):

          class Meta:
             proxy = True


     class ActiveCityTickets(ActiveTickets):
          class Meta:
             proxy = True
```

Obviously, I could just copy and paste all of the fields in Ticket (there are many), but that is not the right way of doing it.  I've tried to use Abstract inheritance and Mixins (defining the fields in a separate class that is inherited by both Tickets and ActiveTickets).

One issue with abstract inheritance is that the ForeignKey field, parent, is causing issues since it's duplicative and the related_name is the same.  Generally, my attempts have caused my unit and functional tests to fail.

What are some elegant approaches here?  Should I think about creating two separate MySQL tables and then just using a single Model with multiple managers (and db routers)?  Is that reasonable?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps:

```
class Base(models.Model):
    m2m = models.ManyToManyField(OtherModel, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related")

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name

Comment: Hey William, I'm not sure that that answers my question in its entirety, but it's a great link.  I'd never seen that part of the Django docs before. Thanks!